# exporting ang retrieving data from excel to database using php

Tags: php, mysql, excel, character-encoding

I am trying to create a feature in my program where in you could upload data to the database by uploading data from excel (uploading excel file) i have provided the code below but the data in the database is encoded(i provided a screenshot).
is there something wrong with the code?

Excel format:

```
firstname lastname
_____________________
amir       kumar
jhon         doee
```

But this is what the data looks like when inserted into the database:

[image]

This is my index.php:

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="import.php" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">File Upload</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="150">
            <p class="help-block">Only Excel/CSV File Import.</p>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Import" value="Import">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

import.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{   
    //First we need to make a connection with the database
    $host='localhost'; // Host Name.
    $db_user= 'root'; //User Name
    $db_password= '';
    $db= 'testdatabase'; // Database Name.
    $conn=mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password) or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());
    echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        $count = 0;
        $sql_data = "SELECT * FROM person";
        echo $sql_data;
        while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            //print_r($emapData);
            //exit();
            $count++;
            if($count > 1) {
            $sql = "INSERT into person(firstname , lastname) values ('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]')";
            mysql_query($sql);
            echo "success";

        }
        }
        fclose($file);
        echo 'CSV File has been successfully Imported';
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else
        echo 'Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File';
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you say which encoding do you use in mysql table? And what's about the encoding of your file?

Comment: i did not include endoing in myslq table but i think this is enctype="multipart/form-data" thething you mean?

Comment: No it means whether you use UFT8 or whatever in the database itself, not the HTML form

Comment: No I mean "utf-8", or something else?

Comment: BTW why are you using the obsolete `mysql_` library? It's been deprecated for years (no updates, no bug or security fixes) and removed entirely in PHP7. It doesn't support parameterised queries and leaves you potentially vulnerable to sql injection attacks and other issue. You should plan to switch to `mysqli_` or `pdo` as soon as possible

Comment: what i wanted to know is that how to insert data to database from uploaded excel file.

Comment: utf8_unicode_520_ci

Comment: Try putting `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn);` before you run your query. And read https://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql. But also you should upgrade your DB library as mentioned previously. otherwise once you switch to PHP7 your code will simply stop working.

Comment: Is your excel-file a .csv or a .xls(x)?

Comment: That is a good point. If your file is actually a binary-format excel file (and not a CSV) then you are simply extracting binary-encoded text from it line by line, as if it was a text file. This will not work. Well, it will, but you just see the binary-encoded content, not the meaningful content. If that's the case you need to use a library which can read the Excel file format and extract information from it. I think there is at least one such library for PHP, from memory - should be easy enough to find if you google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the Excel file as is.  You see what gibberish you get.

Instead, do one of these:

- "Export" the data from Excel into a .csv file, then `LOAD DATA` into MySQL.
- Use a PHP API that lets you fetch data from Excel.  Then `INSERT` the data into a MySQL table.